# Angular how to get $location after popup a new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

$location gives url information in the current browser address bar. If I open a new window using `var popup = $window.open(url)`, I can get the new window's url in `popup.location.href`, but how can I construct a $location service from that?

I'd like to use functions like $location.search() rather than parse parameters myself.

Comment: not hard to find url parsers as libraries or snippets. Quick google search will give you lots of results

Comment: I can parse it myself, just want to know if angular provide a way to construct $location service for a new window